# How to inject viewModelScope for Android unit test with Kotlin coroutines?

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

## Questions

1. What is the best strategy to inject `viewModelScope` for Android unit tests with Kotlin coroutines?
2. When the CoroutineScope is injected into a ViewModel for unit tests, should the CoroutineDispatcher also be injected and defined using `flowOn` even if it is not needed in production code?

`flowOn` is not needed in the production code in this use case as Retrofit handles the threading on `Dispatchers.IO` in *SomeRepository.kt*, and the `viewModelScope` returns the data on `Dispathers.Main`, both by default.

## Expected

Run a unit test on Android's ViewModel view state values saved in a Kotlin Flow value.

## Observed

> Module with the Main dispatcher had failed to initialize. For tests Dispatchers.setMain from kotlinx-coroutines-test module can be used

The unit test is failing on the first occurrence where a CoroutineScope is hardcoded. `viewModelScope` is utilized so that the coroutine launched will maintain the lifecycle of the ViewModel. However, `viewModelScope` is created from within the ViewModel, which makes it more complicated to inject compared to a CoroutineDispatcher that can be defined outside the ViewModel and passed in as an argument.

## Implementation

*SomeViewModel.kt*

```
fun bindIntents(view: FeedView) {
    view.initStateIntent().onEach {
        initState(view)
    }.launchIn(viewModelScope)        
}
```

*SomeTest.kt*

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class SomeTest : BeforeAllCallback, AfterAllCallback {

    private val testDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
    private val testScope = TestCoroutineScope(testDispatcher)
    private val repository = mockkClass(FeedRepository::class)
    private var loadNetworkIntent = MutableStateFlow<LoadNetworkIntent?>(null)

    override fun beforeAll(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        // Set Coroutine Dispatcher.
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
    }

    override fun afterAll(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
        // Reset Coroutine Dispatcher and Scope.
        testDispatcher.cleanupTestCoroutines()
        testScope.cleanupTestCoroutines()
    }

    @Test
    fun topCafesPoc() = testDispatcher.runBlockingTest {
        coEvery {
            repository.getInitialCafes(any())
        } returns mockGetInitialCafes(mockCafesList, SUCCESS)

        val viewModel = FeedViewModel(repository)
        viewModel.bindIntents(object : FeedView {
            @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
            override fun initStateIntent() = MutableStateFlow(true)

            @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
            override fun loadNetworkIntent() = loadNetworkIntent.filterNotNull()

            override fun render(viewState: FeedViewState) {
                // TODO: Test viewState
            }

        })
        loadNetworkIntent.value = LoadNetworkIntent(true)
        // TODO
        // assertEquals(4, 2 + 2)
    }
}
```

Note: A JUnit 5 test extension will be used in the final version.

## Full error log

> Exception in thread "main @coroutine#1" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module with the Main dispatcher had failed to initialize. For tests Dispatchers.setMain from kotlinx-coroutines-test module can be used
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MissingMainCoroutineDispatcher.missing(MainDispatchers.kt:113)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MissingMainCoroutineDispatcher.isDispatchNeeded(MainDispatchers.kt:91)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:285)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:26)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:109)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:158)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch(Builders.common.kt:56)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch(Unknown Source)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch$default(Builders.common.kt:49)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch$default(Unknown Source)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__CollectKt.launchIn(Collect.kt:49)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt.launchIn(Unknown Source)
>       at app.topcafes.feed.viewmodel.FeedViewModel.bindIntents(FeedViewModel.kt:38)
>       at app.topcafes.FeedTest$topCafesPoc$1.invokeSuspend(FeedTest.kt:53)
>       at app.topcafes.FeedTest$topCafesPoc$1.invoke(FeedTest.kt)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt$runBlockingTest$deferred$1.invokeSuspend(TestBuilders.kt:50)
>       at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestCoroutineDispatcher.dispatch(TestCoroutineDispatcher.kt:50)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:288)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:26)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:109)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:158)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.async(Builders.common.kt:91)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.async(Unknown Source)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.async$default(Builders.common.kt:84)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.async$default(Unknown Source)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runBlockingTest(TestBuilders.kt:49)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runBlockingTest(TestBuilders.kt:80)
>       at app.topcafes.FeedTest.topCafesPoc(FeedTest.kt:47)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>       at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>       at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
>       at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
>       at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getMainLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
>       at android.os.Looper.getMainLooper(Looper.java)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.android.AndroidDispatcherFactory.createDispatcher(HandlerDispatcher.kt:55)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.android.AndroidDispatcherFactory.createDispatcher(HandlerDispatcher.kt:52)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MainDispatchersKt.tryCreateDispatcher(MainDispatchers.kt:57)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.test.internal.TestMainDispatcher.getDelegate(MainTestDispatcher.kt:19)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.test.internal.TestMainDispatcher.getImmediate(MainTestDispatcher.kt:32)
>       at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelKt.getViewModelScope(ViewModel.kt:42)
>       ... 40 more
>   Exception in thread "main @coroutine#1" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module with the Main dispatcher had failed to initialize. For tests Dispatchers.setMain from kotlinx-coroutines-test module can be used
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MissingMainCoroutineDispatcher.missing(MainDispatchers.kt:113)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MissingMainCoroutineDispatcher.isDispatchNeeded(MainDispatchers.kt:91)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:285)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:26)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:109)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:158)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch(Builders.common.kt:56)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch(Unknown Source)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch$default(Builders.common.kt:49)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch$default(Unknown Source)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__CollectKt.launchIn(Collect.kt:49)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt.launchIn(Unknown Source)
>       at app.topcafes.feed.viewmodel.FeedViewModel.bindIntents(FeedViewModel.kt:42)
>       at app.topcafes.FeedTest$topCafesPoc$1.invokeSuspend(FeedTest.kt:53)
>       at app.topcafes.FeedTest$topCafesPoc$1.invoke(FeedTest.kt)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt$runBlockingTest$deferred$1.invokeSuspend(TestBuilders.kt:50)
>       at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestCoroutineDispatcher.dispatch(TestCoroutineDispatcher.kt:50)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:288)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:26)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:109)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:158)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.async(Builders.common.kt:91)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.async(Unknown Source)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.async$default(Builders.common.kt:84)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.async$default(Unknown Source)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runBlockingTest(TestBuilders.kt:49)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runBlockingTest(TestBuilders.kt:80)
>       at app.topcafes.FeedTest.topCafesPoc(FeedTest.kt:47)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>       at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>       at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
>       at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
>       at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getMainLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
>       at android.os.Looper.getMainLooper(Looper.java)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.android.AndroidDispatcherFactory.createDispatcher(HandlerDispatcher.kt:55)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.android.AndroidDispatcherFactory.createDispatcher(HandlerDispatcher.kt:52)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MainDispatchersKt.tryCreateDispatcher(MainDispatchers.kt:57)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.test.internal.TestMainDispatcher.getDelegate(MainTestDispatcher.kt:19)
>       at kotlinx.coroutines.test.internal.TestMainDispatcher.getImmediate(MainTestDispatcher.kt:32)
>       at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelKt.getViewModelScope(ViewModel.kt:42)
>       at app.topcafes.feed.viewmodel.FeedViewModel.bindIntents(FeedViewModel.kt:38)
>       ... 39 more

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Inject and determine CoroutineScope on ViewModel creation

In production, the ViewModel is created with a null `coroutineScopeProvider`, as the ViewModel's `viewModelScope` is used. For testing, `TestCoroutineScope` is passed as the ViewModel argument.

*SomeUtils.kt*

```
/**
 * Configure CoroutineScope injection for production and testing.
 *
 * @receiver ViewModel provides viewModelScope for production
 * @param coroutineScope null for production, injects TestCoroutineScope for unit tests
 * @return CoroutineScope to launch coroutines on
 */
fun ViewModel.getViewModelScope(coroutineScope: CoroutineScope?) =
    if (coroutineScope == null) this.viewModelScope
    else coroutineScope
```

*SomeViewModel.kt*

```
class FeedViewModel(
    private val coroutineScopeProvider: CoroutineScope? = null,
    private val repository: FeedRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    private val coroutineScope = getViewModelScope(coroutineScopeProvider)

    fun getSomeData() {
        repository.getSomeDataRequest().onEach {
            // Some code here.            
        }.launchIn(coroutineScope)
    }

}
```

*SomeTest.kt*

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class FeedTest : BeforeAllCallback, AfterAllCallback {

    private val testDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
    private val testScope = TestCoroutineScope(testDispatcher)
    private val repository = mockkClass(FeedRepository::class)
    private var loadNetworkIntent = MutableStateFlow<LoadNetworkIntent?>(null)

    override fun beforeAll(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        // Set Coroutine Dispatcher.
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
    }

    override fun afterAll(context: ExtensionContext?) {
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
        // Reset Coroutine Dispatcher and Scope.
        testDispatcher.cleanupTestCoroutines()
        testScope.cleanupTestCoroutines()
    }

    @Test
    fun topCafesPoc() = testDispatcher.runBlockingTest {
        ...
        val viewModel = FeedViewModel(testScope, repository)
        viewmodel.getSomeData()
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: ```if (coroutineScope == null) this.viewModelScope
    else coroutineScope```  can be simplifed to ``` coroutineScope ?: this.viewModelScope```

Comment: What happens if you use `@Inject constructor(...)`? How can you inject that scope provider?